# Loop through DataTables table to get all cells content

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery [dataTables](http://www.datatables.net/index) to generate the paginated table on my site.  I need to run a process that grabs all of the data out of a particular column.  Something like :

```
$('.testLink').click(function(){
            var cells = new Array();
            $('#myTable tr td').each(function(){
                cells.push($(this).html());
            });
            console.log(cells);
        });
```

That example grabs everything but I would need just the information from one column of tds.  I guess I could do that by adding a class to all of the tds in that row but I am sure there is a better way.  That is a bonus question..

but what I really want to know is how to get this to work with datatables?  Because the script hides most of the table to put in pagination this function only grabs the cells that are visible.  I played around with `fnGetData` but I am not getting it.  Any ideas?

Comment: what is objective?...getting row data not difficult from API and there are likely examples in the huge download package..post details and code attempts

Comment: yes getting all row data in an array then I need to use that data to run a query.  I have been searching and trying stuff from API for hours but I cant get it so I wanted to give SO a whirl.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To access all the rows, you can do:

```
var rows = $("#myTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
```

In your case, this should work:

```
   $('.testLink').click(function(){
        var cells = [];
        var rows = $("#myTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
        for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++)
        {
            // Get HTML of 3rd column (for example)
            cells.push($(rows[i]).find("td:eq(2)").html()); 
        }
        console.log(cells);
    });
```

Comment: He doesn't want all rows. He wants a specific column in each node.

Comment: I can see how this answers the exact question asked, but I would further wonder what you want to do with those? Reason being, a lot of cell (row and column also) manipulation can be done during the DataTables rendering process using callbacks like `fnRowCallback`.

Comment: but when sorting is applied on any column, your code don't give same data before sorting... which I believe is wrong...

Comment: Saved my life! I just wanna add if you are using a checkbox in a column to select the rows you can use this to get the row content  $('input[name=checkboxID]:checked', $("#myDataTable").dataTable().fnGetNodes()).closest('tr'); and then use the iteration that Andrew posted. Cheers!

Comment: But how if `td` is hidden. How to get the values?

Answer (score 6):

Here's a method using fnGetData()

First get the data from plugin which will be all rows visible or not.  Loop over each row data array, and push index=1( second cell) into new array

```
     oTable = $('#example').dataTable();

      var secondCellArray=[];
      $.each( oTable.fnGetData(), function(i, row){
          secondCellArray.push( row[1]);
    })

     console.log( secondCellArray)
```

EDit : working demo...look in console after render

http://live.datatables.net/apixiv/edit#javascript,html

Answer (score 4):

[`jQuery.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) combined with [`fnGetData()`](http://datatables.net/ref) makes for a compact solution. The following function will return a one-dimensional array containing all the values from `obj_dtable`'s `n`th column:

```
function getDataTableColumn(obj_dtable,n) {
    return $.map(obj_dtable.fnGetData(), function(val) {
        return val[n];
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the "EQ" selector. It starts at the index of "0", so if you have..

```
<tr>
  <td>0</td>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
```

Then by using

```
 $("td").eq(3); // last one
 $("td").eq(2); //returns "2"
```

Make sense?

http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: that won't work on a paginated table, rows not visible don't exist